# Is it possible to do a split to columns in SQL Server (T-SQL) using a regular expression or other means

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a rows of data comprised of a row number and string that is comprised of several sentences (varying numbers). I would like to split columns and pivot (unpivot?) using T-SQL and display the appropriate row number and the individual sentences that comprise the string in each row. Note: each new sentence starts with Capital letters and ends with a period.

My data looks something like this:

```
Row_num   Sting

  1       JOHN SMITH walked quickly to his car. MARY waited outside for a ride. BOB JOHNS called is fired to pick him up. TOM was not present.

  2       SALLY SMITH arrived at work early on. Dave called in sick.  BETTY DOE was on vacation.
```

I would like to be able to split the sentences in each row and end up with something like this:

```
 1 JOHN SMITH walked quickly to his car.
 1 MARY waited outside for a ride. 
 1 BOB JOHNS called is fired to pick him up. 
 1 TOM was not present.
 2 SALLY SMITH arrived at work early on. 
 2 Dave called in sick.  
 2 BETTY DOE was on vacation.
```

I've an written a [regular expression](https://regex101.com/r/eJ3vL3/4) (javascript version of regex) that successfully splits the data but I don't know how to achieve this in T-SQL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can achieve what you want using XML:

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/852fc/13/0)**

Data:

```
CREATE TABLE tab(row_num INT, String NVARCHAR(MAX));

INSERT INTO tab(Row_num, String)
VALUES 
(1, N'JOHN SMITH walked quickly to his car. MARY waited outside for a ride. BOB JOHNS called is fired to pick him up. TOM was not present.'),
(2, N'SALLY SMITH arrived at work early on. Dave called in sick.  BETTY DOE was on vacation.')
```

Main query:

```
SELECT 
     row_num
    ,[sentence] = Split.a.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(1000)')
FROM  
(
     SELECT
        row_num,
        [X] = CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(String, '.', '.</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) 
     FROM tab     
) AS A 
CROSS APPLY X.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
WHERE Split.a.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(1000)') <> '';
```

To work with custom regex you should use [`CLR Table Valued Function`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131103.aspx).

Comment: Many thanks. This works great except when my data includes names like: Mr. Johnson.  or Mrs. Smith: its picks up on the period in the mister abbreviation.   Thanks again.

Comment: @Mutuelinvestor You can patch it using [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/22195/4/0). I know this is poor solution but for full regex support you really should write CLR

Comment: @Mutuelinvestor Also [your regex](https://regex101.com/r/kE2yE4/1) doesn't work with `Mrs. Smith` so my answer  behaves exactly like regex in OP ;)

Comment: @Iad2025 is there any way code could be expanded to handle MRS. as well as MR. JR. SR.

Comment: @Mutuelinvestor Yes use mutliple `REPLACE` [Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5fece/1/0)

Comment: I thought something like WHERE the split value -2 not in (rs,mr,jr,sr) etc

Answer (score 2):

additional variant without using `xml`

**Data sample**

```
DECLARE @tab AS TABLE
    (
      row_num INT ,
      String NVARCHAR(100)
    );

INSERT  INTO @tab
        ( row_num, String )
VALUES  ( 1,
          N'JOHN SMITH walked quickly to his car. MARY waited outside for a ride. BOB JOHNS called is fired to pick him up. TOM was not present.' ),
        ( 2,
          N'SALLY SMITH arrived at work early on. Dave called in sick.  BETTY DOE was on vacation.' )
```

**Query**

```
;
WITH    cte
      AS ( SELECT   n = 1
           UNION ALL
           SELECT   n + 1
           FROM     cte
           WHERE    n <= 200
         )
SELECT  S.row_num ,
        LTRIM(SUBSTRING(S.String, T.n,
                        CHARINDEX('.',
                                  SUBSTRING(S.String, T.n, LEN(S.String))))) AS String
FROM    cte AS T
        JOIN @tab AS S ON SUBSTRING('.' + S.String, T.n, 1) = '.'
                          AND LEN(S.String) > T.n
ORDER BY S.row_num ,
        T.n
OPTION  ( MAXRECURSION 200 )
```

**output**

[image]